# Electron forge start is broken by Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, electron, electron-forge

please help because this thing is driving me crazy. In short when gulp reference is added to electron-forge project app launch fails.

- Node: v8.11.3
- electron-forge: v5.2.2

Package.js snippet:

```
"dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-compile": "6.4.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "2.0.4",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.2",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "2.0.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
electron-forge init gulptest
npm install electron-prebuilt-compile -D
npm install gulp -D
```

Add electron-prebuilt-compile to devDependencies in package.json

```
npm run start
```

App will start normally, but if only one line is added to the index.js start command fails.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
```

Once started console will output error with description:

> c:\projects\electron\vendor\node\src\async-wrap.cc:357 Assertion 'env->async_hooks_init_function().IsEmpty()' failed.

Comment: install gulp as dependencies, not as devDependencies

Comment: Thx for the answer but that did not help. Error message is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is electron issue. There is a bug opened for this and it will be fixed in one of the future releases.